# TextBox should display text in hexadecimal in a specific format

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox

I have a textbox in my xaml file which is editable. Now according to my project requirements content in textbox should only be 0-9 and a-f (hexadecimal values) and textbox should take the input based on hexadecimal values.

Demonstratation:

**12 ab 32 a5 64**

Now if my cursor is at the end and i go on pressing backspace, it shud remove the values as it happens in a general text box.

Now If my cursor is at the beginning of a5, and i press "delete key", the value should become like:

**12 ab 32 56 4**

If my cursor is at the end of a5 and i press the 'delete key" nothing should happen.

I had done this successful in my C++ application as follows:

```
void CMSP430CommPanel::textEditorTextChanged (TextEditor& editor)
{

if(&editor == m_texti2cWrite)
{       
    int count = 0;
    int location;

    String text1 = m_texti2cWrite->getText();
    String text = m_texti2cWrite->getText().removeCharacters(" ");
    String hexString = String::empty;   
    int countCaret = m_texti2cWrite->getCaretPosition();

        for(int i=0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {               
            hexString = hexString + String (&text[i], 1);
            if((i+1) % 2 == 0)
            {
                if(i != text.length()-1)
                {
                    hexString = hexString + T(" "); 
                    count ++;               
                }
            }
            count ++;
        }           

        m_texti2cWrite->setText(hexString,false);

        if(text1.length() == m_texti2cWrite->getCaretPosition())
        {
            m_texti2cWrite->setCaretPosition(count);
        }
        else
        {
            m_texti2cWrite->setCaretPosition(countCaret);
        }
}
```

}

where m_texti2cWrite is the name given to textbox. How can i implement the same case in my wpf application which is MVVM based. I have a textbox which shud take inputs as I said above. please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using MVVM - you could do this via a [Value Converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) - i had a go at doing this, mostly out of curiosity - this seems to work quite well but currently requires an instance of the convertor per control as it is using an instance variable to cache the last known good hex value - im sure you could use it in conjunction with validation to improve it.

**Update**
Okay this seems to work(ish) - allows only 1-9 & A-F, i have had to disable textbox selection as it was causing strange results - i have used an attached behaviour to control the cursor, there may be a better way to do this but i sure dont know how...

The delete behaviour works as you asked (if you delete at the end of a pair it does nothing).

Have a play :)

**Update 2**

Made some changes to get it to work with text selection.

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:HexStringConverter x:Key="HexConverter"></local:HexStringConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox local:TextBoxBehaviour.KeepCursorPosition="true"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding HexValue,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource HexConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**View code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    private string hexValue;
    public string HexValue
    {
        get
        {
            return hexValue;
        }
        set
        {
            hexValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HexValue");
        }
    }


}
```

**Hex Converter**

```
public class HexStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string lastValidValue;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string ret = null;

        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            var valueAsString = (string)value;
            var parts = valueAsString.ToCharArray();
            var formatted = parts.Select((p,i)=>(++i)%2==0 ? String.Concat(p.ToString()," ") : p.ToString());
            ret = String.Join(String.Empty,formatted).Trim();
        }


        return ret;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object ret = null;
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            var valueAsString = ((string)value).Replace(" ",String.Empty).ToUpper();
            ret = lastValidValue = IsHex(valueAsString) ? valueAsString : lastValidValue;                
        }

        return ret;
    }


    private bool IsHex(string text)
    {
        var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9A-Fa-f]*$");
        return reg.IsMatch(text);
    }
}
```

**Textbox behaviour**

```
public static class TextBoxBehaviour
{
    public static bool GetKeepCursorPosition(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(KeepCursorPositionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetKeepCursorPosition(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(KeepCursorPositionProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for KeepCursorPosition.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeepCursorPositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("KeepCursorPosition", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, KeepCursorPosition));


    public static int GetPreviousCaretIndex(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(PreviousCaretIndexProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPreviousCaretIndex(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PreviousCaretIndexProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PreviousCaretIndex.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviousCaretIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PreviousCaretIndex", typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));


    public static string GetPreviousTextValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(PreviousTextValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPreviousTextValue(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PreviousTextValueProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PreviousTextValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviousTextValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PreviousTextValue", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxBehaviour), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private static void KeepCursorPosition(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(textBox_PreviewKeyDown);
            textBox.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
            textBox.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(textBox_Unloaded);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("KeepCursorPosition only available for textboxes");
        }
    }

    static void textBox_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(textBox_PreviewKeyDown);
        textBox.TextChanged -= new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        textBox.Unloaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(textBox_Unloaded);
    }


    static void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //For some reason our e.Changes only ever contains 1 change of 1 character even if our
        //converter converts it to 2 chars with the additional space - hmmm?
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var previousIndex = GetPreviousCaretIndex(textBox);
        var previousText = GetPreviousTextValue(textBox);

        var previousLen = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(previousText) ? previousText.Length : 0;
        var currentLen = textBox.Text.Length;
        var change = (currentLen - previousLen);

        var newCharIndex = Math.Max(1, (previousIndex + change));

        Debug.WriteLine("Text Changed Previous Caret Pos : {0}", previousIndex);
        Debug.WriteLine("Text Changed Change : {0}", change);
        Debug.WriteLine("Text Changed New Caret Pos : {0}", newCharIndex);

        textBox.CaretIndex = Math.Max(newCharIndex, previousIndex);
        SetPreviousCaretIndex(textBox, textBox.CaretIndex);
        SetPreviousTextValue(textBox, textBox.Text);
    }

    static void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        Debug.WriteLine("Key Preview Caret Pos : {0}", textBox.CaretIndex);
        Debug.WriteLine("------------------------");
        SetPreviousCaretIndex(textBox, textBox.CaretIndex);
        SetPreviousTextValue(textBox, textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Richard. Although I didnt try this yet, does it successfully perform all my key operations mentioned in the question above???

Comment: Well ive tried it and it seems pretty good - better than i thought , the only other concern would be the character position when deleting/typing in the middle of a hex value it sometimes jumps to the end if you type quick..

Comment: Well first of all Thanks a lot brother. I used it my application and it seems to have few issues as u mentioned. Firstly when i enter value from 0-9 it takes it with a gap in between every 2 numbers but the cursor position seems to go for toss after entering the 3rd number thus ending up with mixed values. Secondly, it accepts all the letters from A-Z without a gap in between 2 letters thus the hexadecimal format is also not noticed. How can we overcome it? :(

Comment: I will have a look at the cursor issue - but it shouldn't allow any chars except valid hex ones - it works okay for me (classic phrase lol) - are you using the latest code as i did update it..

Comment: It shudnt allow anything apart from a-f and 0-9 ;) Yes I am using the updated code which was done 19 hours ago. lol

Comment: Thanks for the massive code brother :) But looks like this is something which is quite tough for me to understand. Is it pssible for you to implement the C++ code written above to generl c# way??? :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try to use [MaskedTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) from Extended WPF Toolkit.</s>
Sorry, I've looked more attentively to possible mask values in `MaskedTextBox`. There's no mask chars for hex numbers. :(

You should un-mark the answer.
I've posted an [issue](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/18712) at Extended WPF Toolkit's tracker.

Comment: I have never used MaskedTextBox. Do i have to rewrite the logic in C# or is their any other way to do?

Comment: @OwaisWani: you have to set up an input mask for `MaskedTextBox` control and bind control's `Text` with some property of data source. The rest (input formatting) control will do itself.

Comment: @OwaisWani: another way is the validation. You can  use RegularExpressionAttribute and `IDataErrorInfo`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx

Comment: Validation just sais if the input is right or wrong, but doesnt change it. But you could do the manipulation of the input in a converter.