# Failing to convert TextBox_TextChanged() in C++ To C#

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, textbox

I was working on C++ with Juce Library for few months. I had written a code in my project where the formatting of textbox was modified to only hexadecimal values with few features:

**Demonstratation:**

**12 ab 32 a5 64**

Now if my cursor is at the end and i go on pressing backspace, it shud remove the values as it happens in a general text box.

Now If my cursor is at the beginning of a5, and i press "delete key", the value should become like:

**12 ab 32 56 4**

If my cursor is at the end of a5 and i press the 'delete key" nothing should happen. while entering the values space bar should not let spacing bw two values. Only a-f and 0-9 should be allowed to enter.

**Code in C++ here:**

```
void CMSP430CommPanel::textEditorTextChanged (TextEditor& editor)
{

if(&editor == m_texti2cWrite)
{       
int count = 0;
int location;

String text1 = m_texti2cWrite->getText();
String text = m_texti2cWrite->getText().removeCharacters(" ");
String hexString = String::empty;   
int countCaret = m_texti2cWrite->getCaretPosition();

    for(int i=0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {               
        hexString = hexString + String (&text[i], 1);
        if((i+1) % 2 == 0)
        {
            if(i != text.length()-1)
            {
                hexString = hexString + T(" "); 
                count ++;               
            }
        }
        count ++;
    }           

    m_texti2cWrite->setText(hexString,false);

    if(text1.length() == m_texti2cWrite->getCaretPosition())
    {
        m_texti2cWrite->setCaretPosition(count);
    }
    else
    {
        m_texti2cWrite->setCaretPosition(countCaret);
    }
}
}
```

I want the same thing to work in my WPF application. Lets say the general implementation of the same code in C#.

please help!!!

Comment: Can you post the C# you've written so far and we can try to help with that (instead of trying to write the full thing for you)?

Comment: whats with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619165/textbox-should-display-text-in-hexadecimal-in-a-specific-format ? Doesnt that work?

Comment: No i don know what to do. I am into this C# language from past few weeks :( I have never worked on it before :(

Comment: @FlorianGl:  I want a simple approach. I tried to implement the same code given but didnt work out. So i just wanna go ahead with a general approach rather than MVVM based :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (TextChanged-Event of your TextBox):

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox m_texti2cWrite = (TextBox)sender;
        int count = 0;

        string text1 = m_texti2cWrite.Text;
        string text = m_texti2cWrite.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        string hexString = string.Empty;
        int countCaret = e.Changes.ToList()[0].Offset;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            hexString += text[i];
            if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (i != text.Length - 1)
                {
                    hexString = hexString + " ";
                    count++;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }

        m_texti2cWrite.Text = hexString;
        if (text1.Length == countCaret)
        {
            m_texti2cWrite.Select(count, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Changes.ToList()[0].RemovedLength == 0)
            {
                m_texti2cWrite.Select(countCaret + 1, 0);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexString.Substring(countCaret, 1)))
                    m_texti2cWrite.Select(countCaret + 2, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                m_texti2cWrite.Select(countCaret, 0);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexString.Substring(countCaret, 1)))
                    m_texti2cWrite.Select(countCaret + 1, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT (only accept Digits, ControlKeys or a-f):

1. Add this method:

   ```
   private Boolean IsTextAllowed(String text)
   {
       string acceptedChars = "ABCDEFabcdef";
       foreach (Char c in text.ToCharArray())
       {
           if (Char.IsDigit(c) || Char.IsControl(c) || acceptedChars.Contains(c)) continue;
           else return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Add the TextBox_PreviewTextInput-Event to your TextBox

   ```
   private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text);
   }
   ```

Comment: Used your above code. The following issues: 1. It accepts everything i.e. it should accept only 0-9 and a-f. 2. After entering 2 numbers, when i try to enter 3rd number the cursor goes to first location and adds in a reverse manner. Although the way it shud delete numbers is working good :) But everytime the cursor goes to first location

Comment: Alright I wrote a code for restricting oly to 0-9 and a-f. Now what about the Issue no. 2??? :)

Comment: Issue Nr. 2 should already be solved thorugh if (text1.Length == countCaret)
        {
            m_texti2cWrite.Select(count, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            m_texti2cWrite.Select(countCaret, 0);
        }     Make sure that you added this, I edited this part a Little bit later.

Comment: Bang on @Florian Gl :) The only issue is whatever I enter inside the textbox appears reverse. E.g. 12 34 56 appears 65 43 21 and cursor is at the beginning. Delete, backspace everything is fine. Just this issue left :)

Comment: Wow. Now this takes numbers quite well but 2 issues are der: 1. If the cursor is at the end and When i press backspace the program crashes throwing exception at if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexString.Substring(countCaret, 1))) "Index and length must refer to the location within the string" 2. When cursor is in middle e.g. 12 34 56 and  cursor is present after 3 and i press "delete", it becomes 12 35 6 but cursor gets shifted by 1 count. It is present after 5

Comment: Wait there is one minor bug. Whenever i press any letter apart from A-F it throws exception at this line: if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexString.Substring(countCaret, 1))) saying "Index and length must refer to the location within the string" :( :(

Comment: No, not in my programm, that might be because of your way to forbid other keys, try mine (see the Edit)

Comment: Awesome. U nailed it :) Works smoothly. God bless u Florian Gl :)

Comment: Youre welcome. To disable pasting add a DataObject.Pasting-Event to your TextBox and write e.CancelCommand(); into the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CMSP430CommPanel
{
    //C++ TO C# CONVERTER WARNING: The original C++ declaration of the following method implementation was not found:
    public void textEditorTextChanged(TextEditor editor)
    {

if (editor == m_texti2cWrite)
{
int count = 0;
int location;

string text1 = m_texti2cWrite.getText();
string text = m_texti2cWrite.getText().removeCharacters(" ");
string hexString = string.empty;
int countCaret = m_texti2cWrite.getCaretPosition();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        hexString = hexString + (string)(text[i], 1);
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (i != text.Length - 1)
            {
                hexString = hexString + T(" ");
                count++;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    m_texti2cWrite.setText(hexString,false);

    if (text1.Length == m_texti2cWrite.getCaretPosition())
    {
        m_texti2cWrite.setCaretPosition(count);
    }
    else
    {
        m_texti2cWrite.setCaretPosition(countCaret);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: There are no getcaretposition(), gettext() etc available in C# according to me, although there are many ways to do it.